# Read contact using Intent.PICK activity doesnt work for dual sim in android

Tags: android, contacts

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

**This is my code it gives all contact for single sim but when i run same on dual sim it doesnt show the contact**

Answer (score 2):

Android does not have support for dual-SIM devices at the SDK level. Various manufacturers have modified Android to support multiple SIM cards. You will need to contact your device manufacturer and inquire about how to obtain contact data from the second SIM.

Comment: thanks but i just starting contact activity that will show all contact.it works in samsung phone but it doesnt work for lava mobile that has 2 sim.

Comment: @SharadMhaske: Then you will need to contact the manufacturer of the device that is giving you problems, asking them what to do.